# Powershell import-module doesn't find modules Configci

Tags: powershell

I am working with windows 10. I am trying to run the following command

```
Import-Module configci
```

I am getting module not found error.I tried running the command

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

I didn't get the "configci" module in the list.That means my package is missing.

Which package do I add to get the "configci" command running?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using 5.0 version and I need to run command locally.

Comment: did you try `implicit-remoting` it from a win 2016 server? It should let you run it locally. Unless your reason is you're on a standalone machine.

Comment: yes, i want to run the command on standalone machine

Comment: i spent an hour looking, i'm sorry i can't find it. I feel like it's really niche, or Microsoft doesn't care to share what is required.

Comment: I have a feeling it has been removed from microsofts concerns. I found a copy on my windows machine in c:\windows.old and c:\windows You could search your pc for "configci.pcd1" and then use that to add a folder to your module paths.  Mind you even these have help files that are outdated

Comment: I moved the configci folder to my modules folder and named it accordingly, and when i try to install it, i get "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\configci\Microsoft.ConfigCI.Commands.dll'" This really tells me they are trying to phase it out. youll have to copy a lot of backups over to get it running.